# Disable Windows 10 Sounds in Audit Mode or unattend

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, unattended, windows-audit-mode

I am preparing Windows 10 Image and I want to disable Windows sounds (but not applications sounds). I tried two different ways:

1. Audit Mode:
   I enter Audit Mode and modify the registry: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents..., but those registries are reset when I install the Windows. (I have set Shell-Setup_neutral CopyProfile: true in unattend.xml)
2. Unattend:
   I have registry file which I call from Shell-Setup_neutral FirstLogonCommands:

```
CMD /c REG IMPORT C:\noSound.reg
```

But I think FirstLogonCommands are called before any user logs in, thus HKEY_CURRENT_USER cannot be set.

What is the correct way to disable Windows sounds in the custom Windows image?